# Select the Text of the textbox for copy

Tags: wpf, uibutton, copy-paste

here are the steps which should happen

1. new UC loads and a certficate is generated my an exe
2. the address of that certficate is shown in the textbox (which is described below)

   all these steps happen as UC loads.
3. i need a copy button that copy the the path of that textbox.

i am using below code  but as UC loads copy button is disable. Why?

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FFF20C0C" IsManipulationEnabled="False" IsTabStop="False" IsUndoEnabled="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="True">

<Button Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto
            " Command="Copy" Content="Copy certificate address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=label1}"/>
```

Comment: you may want to reword your question.

Comment: English may be a second language but this is not clear.  From your comment what do you mean copy button is "enabling only"?

Comment: @Blam i have redefine the question. is this clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the click event of your button and make the copy there. It should look like that :

```
ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Clipboard.SetText(label1.Text);
}
```

Clipboard.SetText() should copy the text of label1 to windows clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that you're trying to use [ApplicationCommands.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy.aspx). If so, then the copy button will always be greyed out if the button is sitting outside of a `ToolBar` or `Menu`. By default the application commands will receive `FocusScope` when used in a `ToolBar` or `Menu`; otherwise, the `FocusScope` will need to be set manually.

Rather than go into further detail, see the SO question: [Copy Property to Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2564519/9664).